# Managing a long list of values

Tags: vba, excel

I have gotten the script below to work well thanks to the people here at Stackoverflow. It basically removes all rows apart from the ones where the value in column A matches the list of values from the script.

But, I want to run the script on roughly 400 records. When I replace the values **10049, 10046** in the example below with 400 values that follows the same structure (all numbers, each 5 characters long) I get an error message stating;

> Compile error. Syntax error

Is there some restriction on the number of values? If so, is there anyway to do a work around?

I kindly need your advice! Thanks!

// Peter

**This works fine:**

```
Sub DeleteArticles()
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 8 Step -1
    'if ID isn't present in array of IDs to keep, then we delete entire row
    If UBound(Filter(Array(10049, 10046), ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)) = -1 Then
        ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

**And this is what doesn't work**

```
Sub DeleteArticles()
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 8 Step -1
    'if ID isn't present in array of IDs to keep, then we delete entire row
    If UBound(Filter(Array(10049 ,10048 ,10047 ,10046 ,10045 ,10044 ,10043 ,10042 ,10041 ,10050 ,10053 ,10052 ,10051 ,10054 ,10012 ,10010 ,10008 ,10007 ,10006 ,10004 ,10013 ,10022 ,10021 ,10020 ,10019 ,10017 ,10016 ,10015 ,10023 ,10032 ,10030 ,10029 ,10027 ,10024 ,10039 ,10038 ,10037 ,10036 ,10035 ,10034 ,10040 ,10063 ,10062 ,10061 ,10060 ,10059 ,10058 ,10057 ,10056 ,10055 ,10064 ,10066 ,10065 ,10067 ,10195 ,10218 ,10217 ,10216 ,10215 ,10214 ,10213 ,10212 ,10211 ,10219 ,10873 ,10870 ,10868 ,11029 ,11301 ,11302 ,11303 ,11304 ,11305 ,11306 ,11307 ,11308 ,11309 ,11333 ,11331 ,11330 ,11328 ,11327 ,11334 ,11342 ,11341 ,11339 ,11337 ,11353 ,11349 ,11348 ,11363 ,11362 ,11360 ,11359 ,11358 ,11357 ,11374 ,11372 ,11370 ,11369 ,11368 ,11367 ,11387 ,11385 ,11384 ,11383 ,11382 ,11381 ,11380 ,11390 ,10000 ,10002 ,10097 ,10207 ,10206 ,10205 ,10204 ,10203 ,10202 ,10201 ,10208 ,10209 ,10210 ,10230 ,10229 ,10228 ,10227 ,10226 ,10225 ,11040 ,11071 ,11112 ,11110 ,11108 ,11117 ,11215 ,11214 ,11209 ,11226 ,11225 ,11224 ,11223 ,11221 ,11227 ,11236 ,11234 ,11233 ,11232 ,11231 ,11229 ,11228 ,11237 ,11246 ,11245 ,11244 ,11242 ,11240 ,11239 ,11238 ,11247 ,11278 ,11167 ,11169 ,11168 ,11179 ,11191 ,11206 ,11203 ,11201 ,11207 ,11256 ,11255 ,11253 ,11252 ,11251 ,11249 ,11248 ,11257 ,11266 ,11265 ,11261 ,11260 ,11259 ,11267 ,11275 ,11272 ,11270 ,11268 ,11276 ,11083 ,11084 ,11085 ,11088 ,10251 ,10301 ,10302 ,10312 ,10311 ,10310 ,10309 ,10308 ,10307 ,10306 ,10305 ,10304 ,10313 ,10317 ,10316 ,10315 ,10314 ,10323 ,10326 ,10343 ,10348 ,10350 ,10415 ,10414 ,10413 ,10416 ,10423 ,10424 ,10426 ,10428 ,10446 ,10445 ,10444 ,10443 ,10442 ,10441 ,10440 ,10439 ,10438 ,10447 ,10466 ,10465 ,10464 ,10463 ,10462 ,10461 ,10460 ,10459 ,10458 ,10467 ,10471 ,10470 ,10469 ,10468 ,10472 ,10448 ,10449 ,10450 ,10451 ,10452 ,10453 ,10454 ,10455 ,10456 ,10494 ,10495 ,10500 ,10507 ,10508 ,10509 ,10510 ,10511 ,10512 ,10513 ,10514 ,10517 ,10518 ,10628 ,10643 ,10732 ,10731 ,10730 ,10729 ,10728 ,10727 ,10726 ,10725 ,10724 ,10733 ,10742 ,10741 ,10740 ,10739 ,10738 ,10737 ,10736 ,10735 ,10734 ,10743 ,10799 ,10809 ,10808 ,10807 ,10805 ,10804 ,10803 ,10802 ,10801 ,10810 ,10819 ,10818 ,10817 ,10816 ,10815 ,10814 ,10813 ,10812 ,10811 ,10820 ,10829 ,10828 ,10827 ,10826 ,10825 ,10824 ,10823 ,10822 ,10821 ,10830 ,10839 ,10838 ,10837 ,10836 ,10835 ,10834 ,10833 ,10832 ,10831 ,10840 ,10844 ,10843 ,10842 ,10841 ,10845 ,10293 ,10294 ,10303 ,10320 ,10331 ,10344 ,10327 ,10368 ,10367 ,10366 ,10365 ,10364 ,10363 ,10387 ,10381 ,10379 ,10377 ,10373 ,10412 ,10430 ,10432 ,10473 ,10474 ,10477 ,10629 ,10621 ,10620 ,10652 ,10654 ,10744 ,10749 ,10750 ,10751 ,10752 ,10756 ,10291 ,10962 ,10963 ,10964 ,10974 ,10975 ,10971), ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)) = -1 Then
        ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because that line exceeds the length limit for a single line of code (1024 characters). Break it up using an underscore after a comma so you can continue your very long expression on the next line. you will probably have to break it into more than 2 lines.

For example:

```
If UBound(Filter(Array(10049 ,10048 ,10047 ,10046 ,10045 ,10044 ,10043 , _
10049 ,10048 ,10047 ,10046 ,10045 ,10044 ,10043 , _
10049 ,10048 ,10047 ,10046 ,10045 ,10044 ,10043 , _
10971), ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)) = -1 Then
```

Line continuations (underscores) can make a "logical code line" span multiple "physical code lines".

Note that there's also a limit to the number of line continuations you can use on a single logical code line.

This technique can also be useful to line up similar expressions to check for errors, and make it so you can see all of the code at once without having to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Note that there is an (uncomfortably small) limit to the number of line extensions, in the vicinity of 20 or so, within a single procedure.